# Octave plotyy shows only half the x-lables

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure

I try to use plotyy in octave but it shows only half of the x-labels. I think I just don't get how to use xtick and xticklables correctly.

```
xAxis = [800 900 1000 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1600 1700];

figure(1, 'Position', [80, 80, 1680, 1050]);
[ax,h1,h2] = plotyy(xAxis, scale1(:,2), xAxis, scale2(:,2));
set(ax,"xtick", [1:10]);
set(ax, "xticklabel", [num2str(xAxis(1)), num2str(xAxis(2)), num2str(xAxis(3)), num2str(xAxis(4)), num2str(xAxis(5)), num2str(xAxis(6)), num2str(xAxis(7)), num2str(xAxis(8)), num2str(xAxis(9)), num2str(xAxis(10))]);
axis on
set(ax, "linewidth", 4, "fontsize", 12)
set(h1,'linewidth',3)
set(h2,'linewidth',3)
grid on
% Add additional text to the figure
```

The x-Axis should show the values from 800 to 1700 in steps of 100. But it makes steps of 200, so every second label is missing.

Anyone knows how to show all the labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set as many `xticks` as `xticklabels`, so you could do:

```
set(gca,'xtick', 0:0.1:1, 'xticklabel', xAxis )
```

but if you ask me, putting numeric labels that don't correspond to the actual values of the x-axis is a recipe for disaster.

**EDIT** based on your comment you seem to just want to specify more ticks within the existing range. Here's an example. Note that `ax` is an array. You only need to specify ticks for one of the two axes.

```
xAxis = [800 900 1000 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1600 1700];
scale1 = [xAxis.', xAxis.']; scale2 = scale1.^0.5; % example data
[ax,h1,h2] = plotyy(xAxis, scale1(:,2), xAxis, scale2(:,2));
set(ax(1),"xtick", xAxis);
set(ax(2),"xtick", []);
```

Comment: Sadly, this line doen't make it. I still have just half of the x-labels displayed. It's the same when I don't set the xlabels at all. And I don't want to use labels that don't correspond to the actual values. I just want octave to display all the labels and not half of them.

Comment: Forget about labels. Labels are useful when you want to replace "1 2 3" with something like "Mon Tue Wed". What you're asking for is how to specify where exactly to display xticks within that range. I've edited my answer to point this out.

Comment: Yes, maybe my question was poorly formulated. But the code from your edit doen't work like I want. The x-axis still shows just every second x-value.
see: https://1drv.ms/i/s!An9UcbbB3nvyyUKlOz9_Sbx28sqg

Comment: If you copy and run my code (5 lines) as it is, with no other code, on a fresh octave session, this is what you get on your machine? This is very weird. If this isn't the only code you're running, all I can say is that somewhere along the way you're running a command that switches `xtickmode` back to `auto` again. What does `get(ax(1), 'xtickmode')` return at the end of your code? `auto` or `manual`? (and if it's `manual`, what does `get(ax(1), 'xtick')` return?

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I only used your code, it worked. The xtickmode in my code was set to auto. I figured out that there was an <pre>axis on</pre> what caused the xtickmode to reset to auto. After removing that command, your solution worked fine.